# Maven seems to be using an older version than the one I expect

Tags: java, maven

I'm having a strange problem with maven. I'm not sure yet what it is but it seems that when compiling my project (with mvn clean compile) somehow a wrong version of a dependency seems to be included.

The library I want to include is **commons-io version 2.4**. When I check my IDE it looks like the correct version is loaded. Compiling in my IDE works fine.

However when I compile the project with maven this line of code fails:

```
FileUtils.write(new File(propertyService.getStatusPageLocation()), "Some string value");
```

Because of the error:

```
[ERROR] /C:/projects/my-project/client-externalclient/src/main/java/be/roots/myproject/client/externalclient/jobs/WriteStatusPageJob.java:[60,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method write(java.io.File,java.lang.String)
```

As far as I can tell the class does have the method with that signature.
The problem seems to happen only on my pc.

A dependency:tree command shows the following info:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ shared-internal ---
[INFO] be.roots.myproject:shared-internal:bundle:3.40-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- be.roots.myproject:shared-external:jar:3.40-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.7:runtime
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.0.4.redhat-621107:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.0.4.redhat-621107:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.0.4.redhat-621107:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.19.0-GA:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.2:test
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-sql:jar:2.15.1.redhat-621107:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.15.1.redhat-621107:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1.redhat-7:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.51:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-web-api:jar:6.0:provided
[INFO] \- be.roots:zxing-osgi:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.zxing:javase:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO]    \- com.google.zxing:core:jar:2.3.0:compile
```

which also shows the correct library being loaded.

the dependency:build-classpath command gives this list:

```
C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\be\roots\myproject\shared-external\3.40-SNAPSHOT\shared-external-3.40-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.7\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs\3.0.4.redhat-621107\cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-3.0.4.redhat-621107.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-core\3.0.4.redhat-621107\cxf-core-3.0.4.redhat-621107.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\woodstox-core-asl\4.4.1\woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\xmlschema\xmlschema-core\2.2.1\xmlschema-core-2.2.1.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\javax\ws\rs\javax.ws.rs-api\2.0.1\javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.2\javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\apache\cxf\cxf-rt-transports-http\3.0.4.redhat-621107\cxf-rt-transports-http-3.0.4.redhat-621107.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\joda-time\joda-time\2.5\joda-time-2.5.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\1.10.19\mockito-core-1.10.19.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\2.1\objenesis-2.1.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\powermock\powermock-api-mockito\1.6.2\powermock-api-mockito-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-all\1.10.19\mockito-all-1.10.19.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\powermock\powermock-api-support\1.6.2\powermock-api-support-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\powermock\powermock-core\1.6.2\powermock-core-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.19.0-GA\javassist-3.19.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\powermock\powermock-reflect\1.6.2\powermock-reflect-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\powermock\powermock-module-junit4\1.6.2\powermock-module-junit4-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\powermock\powermock-module-junit4-common\1.6.2\powermock-module-junit4-common-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\apache\camel\camel-sql\2.15.1.redhat-621107\camel-sql-2.15.1.redhat-621107.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\apache\camel\camel-core\2.15.1.redhat-621107\camel-core-2.15.1.redhat-621107.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\3.2.12.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\3.2.12.RELEASE\spring-tx-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-core\2.2.11\jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.11\jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1.redhat-7\commons-collections-3.2.1.redhat-7.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.7\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\com\jcraft\jsch\0.1.51\jsch-0.1.51.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.2.12.RELEASE\spring-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\3.2.12.RELEASE\spring-context-support-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.2.12.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.2.12.RELEASE\spring-context-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.2.12.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.1.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\commons-net\commons-net\3.3\commons-net-3.3.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\18.0\guava-18.0.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\dataformat\jackson-dataformat-xml\2.6.3\jackson-dataformat-xml-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.6.3\jackson-core-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.6.3\jackson-annotations-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.6.3\jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations\2.6.3\jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.6.3.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\3.1.4\stax2-api-3.1.4.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\javax\javaee-web-api\6.0\javaee-web-api-6.0.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\be\roots\zxing-osgi\1.0\zxing-osgi-1.0.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\com\google\zxing\javase\2.3.0\javase-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\MyName\.m2\repository\com\google\zxing\core\2.3.0\core-2.3.0.jar
```

Does anyone know what else I can try to debug this issue?

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: If i correctly look the FileUtils.write(File, CharSequence) and not FileUtils.write(File, String) ?

Comment: I forgot to include a variable. I'm passing a string as the second parameter (which is a CharSequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was wrong, it turned out to be a rather exotic problem.

For another project I have installed the advanced image API (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/jai-142803.html) which involves adding extra .jar files to your java sdk that will be included in your core java installation.

Among all the libary's .jar files was an older version of commons-io as well, which was included as the default.

Once I removed that library everything went well.

Answer (score 1):

Something that can be different between your IDE and the `mvn` command is the Java version employed. Please check your PATH

Comment: Anything specific I should check my path variable for?

Answer (score 0):

Check your maven settings in your ide.
It is possible to have a different maven path and a custom settings.xml in the IDE selected.

Comment: I mean that compiling the project works in my IDE, when I use the maven integration in my IDE to build it it also fails with the same error.

Comment: I would check the two jar files and java version if they are equal.